# Loop function over data frames and put data in new column

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have looked at some other posts that seem similar, but none of the solutions have worked for my specific situation.

I have several data frames and need to figure out how many of them have NAs as 50% or more of their contents. I've created this function to determine NA percentage for one dataframe:

```
(sum(is.na(df)))/(nrow(df)*nrow(df))
```

This works when I run it on individual dataframes. However, when I try to loop this over the whole list of dataframes, they all return "numeric(0)" or a similar error.

Ideally, I'd be able to store all of these values in a new dataframe as well (na_percents). A sample code that I've generated so far is below. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
#Sample Data
counts1<-c(NA, 1,1,1,1,1,5,NA,NA,2, 3, 4, 3,3,2,NA)
counts2<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,4,2,4, NA,5,2,3,NA,NA)
counts3<-c(5,5,1,3,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA, 4,3,2,1,1,NA)
head1<-c("Steve", "Charlie", "Kam", "Tom")
head2<-c("Chris", "Ellie", "Ben", "Louis")
head3<-c("Paul", "Tammy", "Sheila", "Sara")

df1<-matrix(counts1, nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
df2<-matrix(counts2, nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
df3<-matrix(counts3, nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)

colnames(df1)<-head1
rownames(df1)<-head1

colnames(df2)<-head2
rownames(df2)<-head2

colnames(df3)<-head3
rownames(df3)<-head3

df1<-as.data.frame(df1)
df2<-as.data.frame(df2)
df3<-as.data.frame(df3)

dataframes<-c("df1","df2","df3")

na_percents<-NULL
na_percents$dfs<-dataframes
na_percents<-as.data.frame(na_percents)
```

```
# Loop Attempt 
for (x in dataframes) {
  na_percents$percents<-(sum(is.na(x)))/(nrow(x)*nrow(x))
}
```

This gives me the error "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "percents", value = numeric(0)) :
replacement has 0 rows, data has 3"

I've also tried using lapply:

```
#lapply Attempt
lapply(dataframes, function(x) (sum(is.na(x)))/(nrow(x)*nrow(x)))
```

Which gives me "numeric(0)" for all dataframes.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You likely need to create the `dataframes` object as a list of of dataframes, e.g. `dataframes<-list(df1,df2,df3)`. Then the `lapply` solution should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking to your original code as much as possible, you can do this in your `for` loop with:

```
na_percents <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = length(dataframes)))

for(i in seq_along(dataframes)){
  na_percents[,i] <- (sum(is.na(get(dataframes[i]))))/(nrow(get(dataframes[i]))*nrow(get(dataframes[i])))  
}

names(na_percents) <- dataframes

#    df1    df2   df3
# 1 0.25 0.5625 0.375
```

If you wanted the values in rows instead of columns, a slight tweak:

```
na_percents <- data.frame(perc_na = matrix(NA, nrow = length(dataframes)))

for(i in seq_along(dataframes)){
  na_percents[i,] <- (sum(is.na(get(dataframes[i]))))/(nrow(get(dataframes[i]))*nrow(get(dataframes[i])))  
}

rownames(na_percents) <- dataframes

#     perc_na
# df1  0.2500
# df2  0.5625
# df3  0.3750
```

You could also use `sapply` in the following way, wrapping it in `data.frame()`

```
na_percents <- data.frame(perc_NA = sapply(list(df1, df2, df3), function(x)
  (sum(is.na(x))) / (nrow(x) * nrow(x))))

#   perc_NA
# 1  0.2500
# 2  0.5625
# 3  0.3750
```

Another method is to use `do.call` with `lapply`:

```
na_percents <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list(df1, df2, df3), 
                      function(x) (sum(is.na(x))) / (nrow(x) * nrow(x))))
rownames(na_percents) <- dataframes

#       [,1]
# df1 0.2500
# df2 0.5625
# df3 0.3750
```

As mentioned in the comments, you may be able to optimize your actual calculations with:

```
sum(is.na(x)) / prod(dim(x))
```

Comment: `nrow() * ncol()` makes more sense in the denominator than `nrow()*nrow()`.

Comment: @MarBlo Agree, and `prod(dim(x))` would be even better but as I mentioned I stuck to the OP code as much as possible. This  was less about the function itself and more about the data management so I didn’t bother to change it - could be any function x. Thanks!

Comment: I did the nrow*nrow because the matrices will always have equal rows and columns, but I didn't want the row names counted as a column. Nevertheless, thank you for the help! The sapply and do.call methods were giving me errors, but the loops ran great. Very helpful!